# É possível ler dados do DevTools do chrome usando Selenium?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função do selenium que permita ler dados/logs dos painéis do devtools chrome. Especificadamente:

- Ler a estrutura de HTML da página inteira, ou de algum elemento específico.
- Ler o retorno de algum disparo específico no painel de network.

Obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi, por que você quer ler informações do devtools?